# Python 3.5 "name 'i' is not defined."

Tags: python, python-3.5

I am an absolute beginner to programming.

The issue I am having is not being able to have the inputs be sent to the modulo line where the "if statement " begins.

My aim is, after the three inputs are entered, only the input that is divisible by  5 should be printed.
I get an error:   NameError: name 'i' is not defined.

I have not been able to figure out how to fix this so, I am asking for help please. The code is below:

```
bo=0
xo=0
zo=0
while True:
    bo,xo,zo=[int(i)for i in input('Enter three numbers:  ').split(" ")]
    print([bo,xo,zo])
    if i%5 == 0:
        print([i])
    else:
        print('Sorry')
```

Comment: The obvious issue:  `i` is only defined in the scope of the list comprehension and doesn't exist *anywhere* else.  The deeper issue:  what is it you're actually trying to accomplish?

Comment: `bo=0; xo=0; zo=0` are totally pointless statements, btw

Comment: "only the input that is divisible by 5 should be printed". What happens if more than one of them is divisible by 5? If you're thinking "it should print all of them", then you're treating `i` as if it were simultaneously one value and multiple values. If `i` is a list, you can't do modulus to it; if it's an integer, it's only one value.

Comment: Also, if you are an absolute beginner, don't use list-comprehensions.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: There's nothing wrong with learning list comprehensions early.  I think that was among the *very* first thing I learned with Python.  But that's honestly besides the point.

Comment: bo=0; xo=0; zo=0 are used for the three input values.  The  code works up to that point then fails.

Comment: @Makoto I **entirely** disagree. It is best to learn and understand things like basic flow-control, ideas like scope, etc, which were clearly glossed over. You **never need a list comprehension**, you *do* need those other things.

Comment: People who write tutorials (and answers on SO) have an, in my opinion, regrettable tendency to recommend using list comprehensions for everything. Consider rewriting this code with an ordinary `for` loop, which will behave differently and may shed light on why the original code was wrong.

Comment: @ABoima right, **again, those are totally useless statements**, You **never do anything with `bo, xo, zo` until you assign *other values to it*. You *don't need it at all*.

Answer (score 2):

You say in your requirements

> My aim is, after the three inputs are entered, only the input that is
>   divisible by 5 should be printed

Yet, you print something when something isn't divisible by 5... The word "***sorry***"

**Anyways here is my answer**:

```
[print(i) for i in input('Enter three numbers: ').split() if int(i) % 5 == 0]
```

It will print `i` if it is divisible by 5. Otherwise it won't print anything.

Need it to print as a list?

```
print([int(i) for i in input('Enter three numbers: ').split() if int(i) % 5 == 0])
```

Comment: Please explain the reason why you put the entire code in square bracket for the first solution.The solutions are wonderful but I just need to comprehend why you did it .  In the second solution the "print" key word was left out of the square bracket.

Comment: You need to put some sort of iterable syntax in order to use list comprehensions. You should have already noticed that removing the square brackets gave you a Syntax Error. It technically does not have to be square brackets as you can also use `()` as well for Tuples. using `{}` will use a dictionary or set comprehension depending on how you use it. First solution is printing `i` for every i in the list. The second solution is printing a list after it was created. It should have been pretty self explanatory if you understand the idea of a list comprehension.

Comment: If the second solution isn't obvious to you, then I suggest going back and learning for loops first, then understanding how short for loops could be easily turned into one liner list comprehensions.

Comment: Just for extra clarity, the first solution will create a list of None's because print(i) always returns None.

So if you were to enter 20 30 40 as the input, the list would end up as [None, None, None] because 3 things were put into the list. However, we are not printing the list, so you will only see the outputs of `i`

Comment: Many thanks for finding the time to answer my question. In solution 1 the "print " key word inside the square brackets confused me a bit but now I understand.  Thanks you very much xNinjaKittyx.

Comment: I would appreciate marking my answer if it has helped you.

Answer (score 0):

input('Enter three numbers:  ').split() takes space seperated integers and contverts them to a list as ['30','40','2']
map applyes int function to all elements of ['30','40','2']  list converting it to [30,40,2]
Now I have my list prepared I just need to iterate over the list and check if its item is divisible by 5 and print number or 'sorry' based on remainder obtained after division.

```
items = map(int,input('Enter three numbers:  ').split())
for item in items:
  if item%5 == 0:
    print (item)
  else:
    print ('sorry')
```

output:

```
Enter three numbers:   30 40 2
30
40
sorry
```

Comment: You're probably right but you *need* to explain your code.

Comment: After the three inputs are entered, it should select the once that is divisible by 5 and print them out.

Comment: Enter three numbers:   30 40 2 - here 30,40,2 are inputs entered by user, on the next line 30,40 are divisible by 5 so are printed, 2 is not divisible by 5 so sorry is printed.

Comment: Thanks for the tip @Makoto, I was about to edit and write explanation of my code. Now that I have comment ability I would be writing comments instead of writing answers. It was somehow extremely difficult to get initial 50 reputation in stackover flow.

Comment: This is going in the right direction Sir but the output should be printed as a list.

Comment: what about sorry then, could you comment your output for input 30 40 2.

Comment: The solution provided by xNinja  and prudhvi Indana is what I was looking for. Many many thanks for your quick answers